# Sending user notifications in microsoft teams

Tags: rest, microsoft-teams

I want to implement a notification mechanism similar to slack notifications from gitlab, github etc.

I went through microsoft teams docs and I couldn't find an API to send a message (with REST) for a particular user (based on e-mail address).

Is it possible to do such notification mechanism in microsoft teams?

Answer (score 1):

It -is- possible, but it's definitely different. It's easy to do it to a channel inside a Team in Teams, using webhooks, but for an individual user you need to create a bot, have the user install the bot, and then send something called a "proactive message".

Here are some links:

- [incoming webooks](https://www.google.com/search?q=teams+webhooks&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIL812IL812&oq=teams+webhooks&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j0i22i30l5j69i60.4444j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
- [bot framework](https://dev.botframework.com/) (this is Microsoft's standard bot development platform, and Teams is considered a communications 'channel'. There's tons of guidance on this site, including to a long list of samples)
- [Teams bot docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-for-teams)
- [proactive messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet)

If you want a much quicker/easier option, you could look to use Power Automate / Flow, which has a very simple action to notify a user.

Comment: Sounds like reinventing the wheel despite the fact that such notifications is quite a common feature...

Comment: yes, this kind of notification is much more of a pain than it should be. I've posted an update with a much quicker/easier option though.

Comment: This power automate flow was indeed quicker option, but still depending on customer I would like to have all possibilites. From my understanding in case of creating a custom bot, I need to setup MS Team channel for sending notifications to the user, and a direct channel to send messages via REST (from my system) to the bot?

Comment: so you don't need "direct" channel at all. If you want to call from your system, just make your own api/endpoint (a bot is just an https endpoint, so you could create your own in your project)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Graph now provides an endpoint for sending notifications directly to a user's activity feed: [Send activity feed notifications to users in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications)

Should be easier than setting up a pro-active bot, although the requirements also include an app that is installed for the users you want to notify.